# MATLAB: 2-Band Blending on the following stitching

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, blending, image-stitching, color-blending

Let us say I got two images and stitch them together. 
Now, how could we use a 2-Band Blending on this? 
Or other simple blending approach, I got limited time. Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

What I am using now is straight forward and not consider a Blending Approach:

```
merge_output = output1 .* 0.5 + output2 .* 0.5;
figure, imshow( merge_output, 'XData', xdata , 'YData', ydata ), axis on, impixelinfo;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplified solution I found:

[image]

1. Merge
2. Separate high and low frequency channels
3. Smooth them respectively

Acknowledgement: Adobe® Data-set.

Comment: Everything submitted on Stack Overflow uses a [Creative Commons Share-Alike license](http://stackexchange.com/legal) - adding any other copyright notice is not necessary.